# Cannot download default remote config from Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

I have a trouble with download default remote config from Firebase remote config.

I use this for translates in my android app, but I want default translators insert into app when user haven't internet network (when launch app without network).

But I don't know how can download this remote configs as xml or JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use java version from this tools

https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-rest

Comment: Calling the REST API requires that you have a network connection. The key is that you can/must define a default value for any configurable key that you define (either through the REST API or through the Firebase console). This default value is then baked into the application binary that you ship to your users.

Answer (score 0):

From the Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/parameters):

> When using Firebase console, you **define one or more parameters (key-value pairs) and provide in-app default values** for those parameters. You can override in-app default values by defining service-side parameter values using the Firebase console.

So when you define a parameter, you also define the default value for that parameter, which is then hard-coded into your application. This is what the Remote Config API will return when the app first starts, and if it isn't able to get newer values from the server.